# Element in a responsive design disappears only at a specific window size

Tags: responsive-design

The menu works great, except for a small range of screen sizes, around 764px.
The menu disappears.

http://pitts.mightysharp.co/wordpress/blog/test/

The break points cover it.

They are:
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)

@media (max-width: 767px)

Comment: I commented out this line
//cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
and it works.
I'm not sure why that line is there